# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: '' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: asp.net

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Server Error in '/pi' Application.

'Dexsys' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Dexsys' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Source Error: 


Line 108:        Dim dsTop1 As New DataSet
Line 109:        Dim daTop1 As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL3, cnIT3)
Line 110:        daTop1.Fill(dsTop1)
Line 111:        cnIT3.Close()
Line 112:

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pi\admin\rptSummary.aspx.vb    Line: 110 
Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): 'Dexsys' is not a recognized built-in function name.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1789294
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5340642
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +377
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +137
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +140
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +316
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +88
admin_history.getTimes() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pi\admin\history.aspx.vb:109
admin_history.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pi\admin\history.aspx.vb:217
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212
```

Here is the function causing the probelm:

```
Private Sub getTimes()
    Dim strSQL3 As String = "select datetimestamp, cast(datepart(yyyy, datetimestamp) as varchar(4))  + '-' + cast(datepart(mm, datetimestamp) as varchar(2)) + '-' + cast(datepart(dd, datetimestamp) as varchar(2))  as yyyyddmm, datepart(hh,datetimestamp) * 3600 + datepart(mm,datetimestamp) * 60 as protime, datepart(hh,datetimestamp) * 3600 + datepart(mm,datetimestamp)  + 18000 as protimeplus5 from dex_racklabels.dbo.inv_master where recid = " & Session("INVID")

    Dim cnIT3 As New SqlConnection
    cnIT3.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("csracklabels").ConnectionString
    cnIT3.Open()

    Dim dsTop1 As New DataSet
    Dim daTop1 As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL3, cnIT3)
    daTop1.Fill(dsTop1)
    cnIT3.Close()

    If dsTop1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Session("intTm1") = dsTop1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("protime")
        Session("inttm2") = dsTop1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("protimeplus5")
        Session("yyyyddmm") = dsTop1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("yyyyddmm")
        Session("datetimestamp") = dsTop1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("datetimestamp")
    End If
End Sub
```

So I have tried to google this issue, and it always seems to be that we are passing something stupid over to SQL that is not recognized as a function.... But how am I getting 'Dexsys' when I don't have anything like that in this function?

Also when I cut out that strSQL3 and put it into SQL and run it.. it runs fine... Could it be the where at the end?  How can I stop the code and display the value in the variable: Session("INVID")... I am used to just being able to do response.write(Session("INVID")) and then a response.end()...

I have come accross this issue a couple of times, and would really like to understand how to correct it and why it is happening. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...

1) I can use response.write and response.end lol... Stupid of me for not actually trying that...

2) Dexsys (2015-9-16) was what was in the Session Varaible... hence the error of the built in function!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i guess that your problem is with you Session("INVID") you could use the debug mode to check the variable name in the Visual Studio or show it in the Debug Session Like

```
Debug.Writeline(strSQL3)
'or
Console.WriteLine(strSQL3)
```

You could also wrap the function in Try Catch Exception so you could check better the error that is happenning. You could also get the specific version of the Exception to find more info.

Like this

```
    Try
        'your code goes here.
    Catch ex As SqlException
       throw
    End Try
```

Comment: How can I see these writelines? F12 of chrome browser shows nothing under console

Comment: You need to understand that the Console.Writeline and Debug.Writeline are function from the .NET, so you need to be using the Visual Studio and see in the View > Console to check the messages.
Things like console in browser will only work for javascript functions. like console.log('hi')